# Alternative for UIAppDelegate in Android, a common code which will be called before any activity

Tags: android, android-activity

We are building a security mechanism in our **Android App**, for which we need to ensure that we ask user for password every time they enter the app (even when it is running in background). For this I had to write the checks in all **onRestart** of every activity.

Looking for something similar to iPhone's **AppDelegate** where the code will be called before the activity and I can handle it in central place.

Let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i've done it in an app with similar functionality was the following:

- Create a BaseActivity class
- Overwrite the `OnStart()` here and implement your security
- Extend all activities that need this with the BaseClass

This way you'll have a central place to do your security mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Nick this seems like a right way to solve it, I will try this out right away